# rsync directories

Tags: linux

I'm trying to sync my music collection between my mac and my linux workstation but fails to mirror from my server share to linux.

rsync -avz --progress Music/ /volumes/myserver/music works fine but the reverse on my linux ws doesnt.

rsync -avz --progress /path/to/samba/share/music/ ~/Music does nothing..

Any clue what I have gotten wrong with this??

Best Regards Anders Olme

Comment: What kind of "nothing"?  No output at all?

Comment: Also, you might want to consider rsyncing between the hosts using ssh, rsh or rsyncd, instead of using samba.  A lot of the power and efficiency of rsync is lost if samba has to read the whole file first over the network to find differences.

Comment: I out puts nothing at all on the linux side.. Could try to use ssh instead but it is nice to be able to use tab-completion when you input the paths. Is rsyncd the prefered method or is it more kosher to use the ssh variant?

Answer (score 1):

I would try with the full path and adding some -vv option could also help.  The -n (dry-run) option is also your friend.

```
rsync -n -avvz --progress /path/to/samba/share/music/ /Users/Someone/Music
```

Comment: Adding more v didnt make any difference no more text output just a few seconds wait and then nothing.

Comment: do you have 'similar' version of rsync on both machines ?  Personally, as Rog mention, I also use ssh for doing it

rsync -n -avz --stats -e ssh User@machine1:/path/Music /Users/Someone/Music